# Laravel query builder multiple column in where comparison

Tags: laravel, multiple-columns, where-clause, query-builder

I'm using query builder with laravel and i'm trying to get the equivalent of

```
SELECT name
     , firstname 
FROM emp
WHERE name+' '+firstname LIKE '%test%'
```

in query builder? How could I have the same result?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you even looked at the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that in `whereRaw()` like this

`DB::table('emp')->whereRaw("name+' '+firstname LIKE '%test%'")->select('name', 'firstname')->get();`

hope it's work for you!

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is what i'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
 $result = DB::table('emp')->select('name', 'firstname')->where(DB::raw("CONCAT('name', ' ', 'firstname')"), 'LIKE', '%'. 'test' .'%')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CONCAT` for multiple column

```
DB::table('emp')->Where(DB::raw("CONCAT(`name`, ' ', `firstname`)"), 'LIKE', "%test%")->select('name', 'firstname')->get();
```

hope this will help.